# Apache error log shows '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND' error

Tags: php, macos, apache, safari, osx-elcapitan

When i try to load my local server having name "local.test.com" the browser shows "Safari can't find the server" and the apache error log shows these outputs

```
AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
AH00094: Command line : '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

Does anyone knows why this is happening.? What the last line of output really means ?? 
When i tried 127.0.0.1 as the url my project login page code is displayed on the browser.

**Note that i've changed my DocumentRoot** from "/Library/WebServer/Documents"  to "/Users/myaccount/webroot/projectname"

My System Os:- OSX El Capitan
Apache Version: 2.4.18
Php version: 5.5.34
Mysql version: 5.7.13

Comment: i suggest asking on server fault

Comment: Oh.. Okay... Then I will ask this on server fault.. Thanks